# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate

Tags: android, sockets

I m trying read XML data using XML parser from Url("https://....etc").
But I'm facing below error.
This is my log.

> 04-08 16:34:23.017:
>   WARN/System.err(8052):
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not
>   trusted server certificate
>
> 04-08
>   16:34:23.098: WARN/System.err(8052):
>   at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:371)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.107:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:92)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.107:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:381)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.107:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:164)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.116:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.116:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.116:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.116:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.127:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.127:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.127:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   androidexperts.apps.prontonnetworks.xmlparser.(xmlparser.java:108)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.196:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   androidexperts.apps.prontonnetworks.prontonnetworks$HandlerServer.doInBackground(prontonnetworks.java:486)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.232:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   androidexperts.apps.prontonnetworks.prontonnetworks$HandlerServer.doInBackground(prontonnetworks.java:1)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.257:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.287:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.307:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.317:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.317:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.317:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.317:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): Caused by:
>   java.security.cert.CertificateException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
>   TrustAnchor for CertPath not found.
>   04-08 16:34:23.327:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:168)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.327:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:366)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.337:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): ... 18 more
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.337:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): Caused by:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
>   TrustAnchor for CertPath not found.
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.377:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:149)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.377:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:202)
>
> 04-08 16:34:23.377:
>   WARN/System.err(8052): at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:164)

any one know about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are attempting to connect to an HTTPS URL via and the SSL certificate provided by the site is not trusted by the devise you are running the code on. I suggest you read [this question on setting up trust in the Apache HTTP Client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2642777/278836).

Comment: i m getting error on this line registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

Comment: Somehow I doubt that since I don't see Scheme's <init> block in the stack and I do see openConnection in there...