# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate while trying to connect using https with .bks keystore

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594189/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-not-trusted-server-certificate)

I am trying to connect to server using "https" scheme with .bks keystore but i am unable to connect due to this issue.

Can any one tell me what's the reason for this and how to solve this.

Here is my code

```
public String httpRestGetCallwithCertificate(String url, String payLoad) {
        String result = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;
        KeyStore trustStore = null;
        try {
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());
            HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

            HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("hostname","portno","https");
            httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort()),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username","password"));
            trustStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

            InputStream instream = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.truststore);
            try {
                trustStore.load(instream, "password".toCharArray());

            } finally {
                try { instream.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
            }
            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
            Scheme sch = new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443);
            registry.register(sch);
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(sch);
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
            if (response != null && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                return "success"
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ConnectTimeoutException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Network connetcion is not available");
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }catch(SocketTimeoutException exception){
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket timed out.");
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.v("IO Exception", exception.toString());
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (httpClient.getConnectionManager() != null) {
                httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }
            httpPost = null;
        }
        return "fail";
    }
```

and below is my stack trace

```
03-06 16:53:50.460: W/System.err(1655): javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
03-06 16:53:50.460: W/System.err(1655):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:137)
03-06 16:53:50.470: W/System.err(1655):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
03-06 16:53:50.470: W/System.err(1655):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:381)
03-06 16:53:50.470: W/System.err(1655):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
03-06 16:53:50.470: W/System.err(1655):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-06 16:53:50.470: W/System.err(1655):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-06 16:53:50.470: W/System.err(1655):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-06 16:53:50.480: W/System.err(1655):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-06 16:53:50.480: W/System.err(1655):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-06 16:53:50.480: W/System.err(1655):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
```

And i am getting the exception while executing below line

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594189/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-not-trusted-server-certificate

Comment: Does this server works with a normal browser? Is there really no peer certificate at all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Danial said while answering below question, 
we should create a custom class from org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory, not the one org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory itself

[Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https)

Comment: Please don't use these sort of trustmanagers. They're insecure and partly defeat the point of using HTTPS in the first place.